# Running Firebase Functions locally with secure connections (HTTPS)

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a react app served with HTTPS (I need it for a service worker running in the background)
that is having CORS issues with my backend running locally with Firebase Functions.

Firebase Functions is just wrapping an express application with CORS module enabled.
I performed a few tests with OPTIONS calls to this backend and I'm getting the proper headers.

They problem is that my Frontend (HTTPS) cannot reach out to my backend (HTTP).
Is there any way to run firebase functions locally with HTTPS instead of HTTP?

running `firebase serve --help` only shows

```
Options:
  -p, --port <port>   the port on which to listen (default: 5000) (default: 5000)
  -o, --host <host>   the host on which to listen (default: localhost) (default: "localhost")
  --only <targets>    only serve specified targets (valid targets are: hosting, functions, database, firestore)
  --except <targets>  serve all except specified targets (valid targets are: hosting, functions)
  -h, --help          output usage information
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local emulator does not support HTTPS at this time. T here is a thread on GitHub about this, with advice to use `ngrok` for a similar use case.   https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues

Comment: Can you point to the specific issue? I searched for there it but it seems difficult to search for the word "https" as it's contained in every issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with native react-scripts:

```
REACT_APP_ENV=development yarn start
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "HTTPS=true sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts start'",
    ...
```

See [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development) docs.

Comment: The question relates to running the functions under https, not react-scripts

Comment: @DirkR did you read the linked documentation page?

Comment: I sure did. However the documentation page points to create-react-app where as the question is not about create-react-app (i.e. frontend), it is about firebase functions which are backend, and usually runs with 'firebase serve' or the local emulator. Author states they are already running the frontend (create-react-app) as https.